# sIFR: fonts stretched in internet explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, sifr

I have a problem with sIFR in Internet Explorer 9. The fonts are stretched. But when mouse is over, then size is ok.

Answer (score 0):

try parameter forceSingleLine: true

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Noby. After add the parameter its not working in ie 9. Is any other suggestion for this issue.  Thanks my dear friend.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, try setting the config parameter sIFR.forceWidth to true.